# How to make my expected json in this code

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have one array using i want to make my json response but i am not able do this:

```
print_r($exist_email);

    Array
(
    [user_id] => 3
)
```

I tried like this

```
$response_array['status']='Exist User';
$response_array['message']='Email already exists.';
$response_array['data']=$exist_email;
$this->response($this->json($response_array), 200);

public function response($data,$status=200){
            $this->_code = ($status)?$status:200;
            $this->set_headers();
            echo $data;
            exit;
        }

protected function json($data){
            if(is_array($data)){
                return json_encode($data);
            }
        }
```

I am getting response

```
    {
    "status": "Exist User",
    "message": "Email already exists.",
    "data": {
        "user_id": "3"
    }
}
```

My expected output

```
    {
    "status": "Exist User",
    "message": "Email already exists.",
    "data": [
        {
            "user_id": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: at this line `$response_array['data']=$exist_email;` you can replace with this `$response_array['data'][0]=$exist_email;` or  `$response_array['data'][]=$exist_email;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comments you should used multidimensional array in this line `$response_array['data']=$exist_email;`

Above line you can replace with below lines

```
$response_array['data'][0]=$exist_email;
```

OR

```
$response_array['data'][]=$exist_email;
```

Here you can check your desired [Output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c50b4f5f71222cc59d3ac38be0e7f47a720b2d8)

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting an array, you can:

```
$response_array['data'] = array();

$response_array['data'][] = $exist_email;
$response_array['data'][] = $exist_email2; /* For the second, (optional) */
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is array of array so you need to have `$response_array['data']` to be an array.

Just replace this line

```
$response_array['data']=$exist_email;
```

with

```
$response_array['data'][]=$exist_email;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take array to get desired output.

You may try below code :

```
<?php

$response_array['status']='Exist User';
$response_array['message']='Email already exists.';
$response_array['data'][]= array('user_id' => 3);

echo json_encode($response_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

check : https://3v4l.org/o2QGX